# ¿Cómo quitar el web de una ruta de Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony3, url

Estoy usando *Symfony 3* y tengo una *URL* como la siguiente:

> http://localhost/marcacionWebBio/web/login

... y deseo que quede así:

> http://localhost/marcacionWebBio/login

Comment: Necesitaría ver la configuración de tu fichero de routing (o al menos, la anotación de enrutado de la acción de login) y tu configuración de servidor web (apache, nginx... el que uses)

Comment: Así a bote pronto, creo que arreglarías si utilizas el comando server:run del propio Symfony. Si quieres tenerlo tal cual lo pones deberías configurar un VirtualHost que apunte ahí. ¿Cual es tu propósito?

Comment: Gracias por su respuestas, les comento mi propósito es tener una url más limpia ya que así lo desea el cliente para evitar escribir una url tan larga, les comento que he probado configurar el VirtualHost con una url mucho más limpia que apunte a esta otra y quedo genial.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Será tema de algún prefix en las rutas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esta configuración de Apache tu URL no tendra el `web/app.php`.

Puedes crear este fichero para tu sitio desde este enlace: http://symfony.es/documentacion/como-configurar-bien-apache-para-las-aplicaciones-symfony2/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      mi-sitio.com
ServerAlias     www.mi-sitio.com

SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER     "..."
SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD "..."

DocumentRoot    "/Proyectos/Symfony2/mi-sitio.com/web"
DirectoryIndex  app.php

<Directory "/Proyectos/Symfony2/mi-sitio.com/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/mi-sitio.com-access.log combined

KeepAlive            On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout     5

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/xml"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg   "now plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda quedo bien.

Comment: @StalinCaiche recuerda votar las respuestas que han sido útiles para que puedan ayudar a otras personas.

Comment: Si pero no me permite votar hasta no tener 15 de reputación :(